# $X - Y$ converges in probability?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Is it true that, if $X$ converges in probability to $A$, and $Y$ converges in probability to $B$, then the difference $X-Y$ converges in probability to $A-B$?

I know this is true for addition, but I cannot find anything about a difference.  What is weird to me is that, in proving that the sample variance $S_n ^2$ converges in probability to $\sigma ^2$, the difference fact is used.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does, just define Z=-Y and use the property for addition

Comment: Ah, smart. Thank you.